# PhoneGap Error: Cannot find module '<project_folder>'

Tags: android, cordova

I've been trying to run a Phonegap application locally with this command:

```
phonegap local run android
```

Though I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Users\OmaR\Desktop\New folder\myapp>phonegap local run android [phonegap] compiling Android...    [error] An error occurred while building the android project. module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\OmaR\Desktop\New'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the same process in some new folder where the folder name does not have any space in it.

In the above case the folder name is "New folder".

Try with folder name without spaces.